# Hearing a popping sound from wall

Tags: walls, interior

Started hearing what sounds like a popping sound coming from inside our bedroom wall. It is part of the exterior to the house, but we have no known water or air ducts along that part of the wall. Any ideas what it could be or who would be able to look at it

Comment: What type of exterior do you have?  Brick, siding?  Maybe a piece of siding is loose and it is being blown around by the wind.  This happened to me .. but was more of a  flapping sound.  And clearly from outside.

Comment: How often does the sound occur? Once every few seconds? Once or twice a day? Also, if you have any outlets along that wall, you can remove the cover plate and listen.

Comment: You might also have an animal of some sort in there.  Squirrel, chipmunk, mouse, etc.

Comment: Woodpecker!  If it's a short series of pops, rest, then another short series, this is a good guess.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need a lot more info before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Popping has a wide possibility of options, electrical? Mechanical , occurring the same time every day? 
I could keep going.

Comment: The key to finding the source of a noise is the investigator. It is a super challenge for people online tell you what is making the noise. We can throw out ideas. But your investigation, to provide us with enough details, will probably identify the source.

Comment: Voting to close. Details lacking and OP hasn't been back. My guess was creaking due to cold weather--my home is firing off rifle shots regularly as we hit -15F.

Comment: Unresolvable question. OP has not been back. Vote to close. Good information to consider in comments though.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what "popping" (I think either popcorn or bubblewrap, neither of which seems likely) means, either:

Dripping water from a roof leak (or from a pipe above traveling a long way sideways, if no pipes in that section of wall - water will go a long way on framing)

or

Some sort of electrical arcing (try shutting off breakers and see if it stops - if it's that, the house you avoid burning down would be your own.)